# I'm a .NET/WCF/Visual Studio programmer. What's a good way to learn Silverlight3 and Blend?

Tags: .net, silverlight

I am familiar with XAML, but I'm no expert. I'm not a designer.

In the past I learned much by examining other people's code, good and bad.

Is this a reasonable approach with Silverlight?  and if so, where can I look at open-source SL projects or examples?

If this is not a good approach, what do you recommend?

Or should I just punt on Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first port of call should be http://silverlight.net/Learn/. This is part of the official Silverlight site and contains tons of useful information.  Then go to http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc136522.aspx for Blend.

There are also plenty of projects with source code on codeplex.com - just search for silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the Silverlight book from Microsoft

Microsoft released it in the Microsoft Press free.
You can download it at:

http://csna01.libredigital.com/?urvs5cn3s8

Although, it is silverlight 2.

Answer (score 0):

First of all yes, I think that's a valid approach.  I learned a lot from reading Tim Heuer's blog.  Also I'd recommend following www.silverlightcream.com and reading as many daily updates as possible.  As for learning Blend 3 and Silverlight 3 at the same time it looks like this book may be helpful:

[http://www.amazon.com/Foundation-Expression-Blend-3-Silverlight/dp/1430219505/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1250531518&sr=8-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219505)